# Call to undefined function dl() php

Tags: php, opencv

i am using following PHP version `PHP Version 5.4.7`. And i am implementing https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP . But when i try to run the example it says

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in C:\xampp\htdocs\OpenCV\opencv.php on line 5
```

Here is the Code

```
<?php
$br = (php_sapi_name() == "cli")? "":"<br>";

if(!extension_loaded('opencv')) {
    dl('opencv.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);
}
$module = 'opencv';
$functions = get_extension_funcs($module);
echo "Functions available in the test extension:$br\n";
foreach($functions as $func) {
    echo $func."$br\n";
}
echo "$br\n";
$function = 'confirm_' . $module . '_compiled';
if (extension_loaded($module)) {
    $str = $function($module);
} else {
    $str = "Module $module is not compiled into PHP";
}
echo "$str\n";
?>
```

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php: _dl() is now disabled in some SAPIs due to stability issues. The only SAPIs that allow dl() are CLI and Embed. Use the Extension Loading Directives instead._

Answer (score 2):

`dl()` is disabled by default in PHP 5.3,  as stated on [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) .

As it suggests, you would want to use the [Extension Loading Directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) instead.

So you're left with one of three options:

1. Load the extension through `php.ini`
2. Use a SAPI that supports and loads `dl()` as a dependency
3. Downgrade PHP to 5.2 so that `dl()` is loaded automatically

Comment: Thanks for the help with the Highlighting David. Still a newb at the site.